# var name = document.getElementById('full-name') not working

Tags: javascript

Hello everyone I am brand new to Javascript just started this month. I have to make form validator for Name, email, address etc. When I tried to store the users name in a var using getElementById it doesn't store the name. Instead when I do console.log(name) it returns [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XpzP7.png)

Here is the code I am trying to use

```js
var name = document.getElementById('full-name')

document.getElementById('purchase').addEventListener('click', function(){
  console.log(name)
  var nameCheck = /^[a-zA-Z]+ [a-zA-Z]+$/
  if(!nameCheck.test(name)){

      document.getElementById('error').innerText += '\nPlease provide a valid name'
  }  
  else{
     console.log('valid name given')
  }
```

```html
<div class="control-group">
  <label class="control-label">Full Name</label>
  <div class="controls">
    <input id="full-name" 
           name="full-name" type="text" placeholder="full name" class="input-xlarge">
    <p class="help-block"></p>
  </div>
```

Comment: `var name = document.getElementById('full-name')` should be `var name = document.getElementById('full-name').value`

Comment: @VLAZ As long as you put it inside of the event listener. Otherwise `name` will always be an empty string.

Comment: @Ivar that's also true.

Answer (score 1):

```
var nameElement = document.getElementById('full-name')
document.getElementById('purchase').addEventListener('click', function(){
        // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11563638/
        var name = nameElement.value // use Dom 's value
        console.log(name)
        var nameCheck = /^[a-zA-Z]+ [a-zA-Z]+$/
        if(!nameCheck.test(name)){
            
            document.getElementById('error').innerText += '\nPlease provide a valid name'
        }  
        else{
           console.log('valid name given')
        }
```